# Partial Response using AutoQuery plugin in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I was wondering if AutoQuery plugin does/will support partial response? Ideally I would like to support following querystring/parameter.

`?...&fields=F1,F5,F8&...`

I found "_select" in "Raw SQL Filters" section but I am not sure I would want enable that.

I also found "ServiceStack.PartialResponse" nuget package but was not sure if that can be used with AutoQuery.

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can now use [AutoQuery Customizable Fields](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#customizable-fields) feature to customize which fields you want returned using the Fields property available on all AutoQuery Services, e.g:

```
?Fields=Id,Name,Description,JoinTableId
```

The Fields still need to be defined on the Response DTO as this feature doesn't change the Response DTO Schema, only which fields are populated. This does change the underlying RDBMS SELECT that's executed, also benefiting from reduced bandwidth between your RDBMS and App Server.

A useful JSON customization that you can add when specifying custom fields is `ExcludeDefaultValues`, e.g:

```
/query?Fields=Id,Name,Description,JoinTableId&jsconfig=ExcludeDefaultValues
```

Which will remove any value type fields with a default value from the JSON response, e.g:

- http://github.servicestack.net/repos.json?fields=Name,Homepage,Language,Updated_At
- http://github.servicestack.net/repos.json?fields=Name,Homepage,Language,Updated_At&jsconfig=ExcludeDefaultValues

Comment: Could I set SelectExpression parameter to achieve this for now? 


`var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, Request.GetRequestParams());
if(<fields exists>)
   q.SelectExpression = "SELECT " + <fields here>;`

Comment: @SamJackSon The preferred API to use is `q.Select(fieldNames)`.